# Android6 camera permission

Tags: android, titanium, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I made an application which uses Camera.

- Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.5,
- Titanium SDK version 5.1.1.GA

It works well on before Android 5 (Lollipop).

However now it crashs on Android 6 without even showing permission prompt.

If you set the Permissions in android setting panel. it works well.

How can I set the permission automatically, when user install?

Is there any good samples?

I am checking this sample code, but honestly speaking 
it is too complicated for only camera permissions.

https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take permission in Android 6:-

```
       public void android6permission{
          String[] permissions = {
                "android.permission.CAMERA",
                "android.hardware.camera",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
                "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        };


        requestPermissions(permissions, 122323);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 122323: {
                if (grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Do task
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Access denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Just run method android6permission() in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 6.0 the permission mechanism is changed. You have to ask for permissions on run-time (when user requests a particular system service). If you are targeting 6.0 and you haven't handled run-time permissions your app will crash.

Check the official documentation below :

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html